# C# float or double choosing pre-compilation

Tags: c#, .net, types, mono, monodevelop

We recently realized we want to replace our all project from double to float while still saving the option to use double sometimes.

The question is: **what is the best practice to do it?**

We thought aliasing is the right thing to do but we've found global aliasing is not supported in C#.
Here is an example for the aliasing we've done:

```
#if USE_FLOAT
using mFloatType = System.Single;
using mComplexType = CenterSpace.NMath.Core.FloatComplex;
using mComplexVector = CenterSpace.NMath.Core.FloatComplexVector;
using mComplexMatrix = CenterSpace.NMath.Core.FloatComplexMatrix;
using mHermitianMatrix = CenterSpace.NMath.Matrix.FloatHermitianMatrix;
#else
using mFloatType = System.Double;
using mComplexType = CenterSpace.NMath.Core.DoubleComplex;
using mComplexVector = CenterSpace.NMath.Core.DoubleComplexVector;
using mComplexMatrix = CenterSpace.NMath.Core.DoubleComplexMatrix;
using mHermitianMatrix = CenterSpace.NMath.Matrix.DoubleHermitianMatrix;
#endif
```

While USE_FLOAT is a define symbol.

However, putting this piece of code in every file in the project (more than 500 files) seems totally wrong, especially in object oriented programming.

Any ideas how to do this transition?

If it helps, we are using monoedevelop 6.3 with Mono 4.0.

Thanks.

Comment: Are those `CenterSpace.NMath.Core.XXXX` classes sealed? If not, you could create an inherited version who's type is determine at compile time (#if/#else) and use those types instead of CenterSpace's ones directly. This would not help with `System.Double` as system types are sealed...

Comment: @SushiHangover Most of them not sealed. Except System.Double as you mentioned and XXX.DoubleComplex.
So we can't inherit them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with sealed types, you could go with a type factory so that `#if/#else/#endif` block is only in one file.

Just an example, there are a few ways to do this:

```
using System;
#region USING_FLOAT
#if USE_FLOAT
using mFloatType = System.Single;
using mComplexType = CenterSpace.NMath.Core.FloatComplex;
using mComplexVector = CenterSpace.NMath.Core.FloatComplexVector;
using mComplexMatrix = CenterSpace.NMath.Core.FloatComplexMatrix;
using mHermitianMatrix = CenterSpace.NMath.Matrix.FloatHermitianMatrix;
#else
using mFloatType = System.Double;
using mComplexType = CenterSpace.NMath.Core.DoubleComplex;
using mComplexVector = CenterSpace.NMath.Core.DoubleComplexVector;
using mComplexMatrix = CenterSpace.NMath.Core.DoubleComplexMatrix;
using mHermitianMatrix = CenterSpace.NMath.Matrix.DoubleHermitianMatrix;
#endif
#endregion

namespace TypeFactory
{
    public static class CenterLineFactory
    {
       public static mFloatType Double { get { return new mFloatType(); } }
       public static mComplexType ComplexType { get { return new  mComplexType(); } }
       ~~~ etc ~~~
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var aFloat = CenterLineFactory.Double;
var aComplexType = CenterLineFactory.ComplexType;
```

But due to the fact this is an afterthought on how your double/float choice is made, it would require all 500 of those files need updated anyway on how you are creating these 5 types...

#### Personally:

I would use Microsoft's `CodeFormatter` (https://github.com/dotnet/codeformatter) to bulk convert all your files at once and insert your `#if USE_FLOAT/#else/#endif` block within a `#region USING_FLOAT/#endregion`.

I normally never use regions, but would for this. This way you could auto-collapse the `USING_FLOAT` region and remove it from creating a ***visual* code smell**.

Comment: That could be an answer but it looked like even you understand it has disadvantages.
What you mention "in person" is currently what we are going to do. Still looking for others ideas to do it right.
It's quite weird there is no way to do it easily.
Thank you for being willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to use composition instead of inheritance and create a SingleOrDouble struct as below which imitates the behavior of Single or Double based on the build symbol.

You will still need to update all 500 files but it will be a simple find all **System.Single** and replace with **SingleOrDouble**

```
    #if USE_FLOAT

public struct SingleOrDouble : IComparable
    , IComparable<Single>, IEquatable<Single> {

    public Single Value;

    private SingleOrDouble(float f) {
        Value = f;
    }

    public static implicit operator float(SingleOrDouble s) {
        return s.Value;
    }
    public static implicit operator SingleOrDouble(float f) {
        return new SingleOrDouble(f);
    }

    public int CompareTo(float other) {
        return Value.CompareTo(other);
    }

    public bool Equals(float other) {
        return Value.Equals(other);
    }

    public static bool IsInfinity(float f) {
        return Single.IsInfinity(f);
    }



    #else

public struct SingleOrDouble : IComparable
   , IComparable<Double>, IEquatable<Double> {

    public Double Value { get; set; }

    private SingleOrDouble(double d) {
        Value = d;
    }

    public static implicit operator double(SingleOrDouble d) {
        return d.Value;
    }
    public static implicit operator SingleOrDouble(double d) {
        return new SingleOrDouble(d);
    }

    public int CompareTo(double other) {
        return Value.CompareTo(other);
    }

    public bool Equals(double other) {
        return Value.Equals(other);
    }


    #endif
    public int CompareTo(object obj) {
        return Value.CompareTo(obj);
    }

    public TypeCode GetTypeCode() {
        return Value.GetTypeCode();
    }

    public static bool IsInfinity(double d) {
        return Double.IsInfinity(d);
    }


}
```

Please note that above class is not complete but you get the idea.

The class variable can be initialised as below

```
    SingleOrDouble s = 100.5;
```

which is no different from intializing a normal double as below

```
    double d = 100.5;
```

Hope this helps